# cannot access a service via nodeport in kubernetes for docker desktop windows

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hello everyone i am trying kubernetes and have the version that comes with docker desktop for windows and i cant seem to access a service which has type nodeport . Following are the related info

```
docker version:

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false



Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false



kubernetes version:

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:25:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

my deployment file:(deployment.yml)

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: tomcat-app
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tomcat-app
          image: tomcatapp:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80


---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcatappservice
spec:

  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: tomcat-app
```

ran it with

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yml
```

cant seem to access the tomcat server at localhost: given by kubernetes also tried explicitly giving a port in deployment file but still cant get it to work

Comment: hi, can you run the following command `kubcetl get svc`

Comment: Hi @SureshVishnoi sure can run get svc command the output shows my service with TYPE column having value NodePort and  Custer-Ip column having some value while External Ip column is none and ports column has 8081:30080/TCP

Answer (score 4):

1. You must have two tags `nodePort: 30007` and `type: NodePort`
   Your service yaml should be like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcatappservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30007
  selector:
    app: tomcat-app
```

2. Test it by `kubectl get services`, and if it succeed, you will see something like `80:30007/TCP`

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello          NodePort       10.96.92.53    <none>        80:30007/TCP   3d3h
```

3. Access your service.

```
$ kubectl describe nodes | grep InternalIP -n1
26-Addresses:
27:  InternalIP:  172.17.0.3
28-  Hostname:    kind2-control-plane
```

or

```
$ kubectl get nodes --output json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
            ...
            "status": {
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "address": "172.17.0.3",
                        "type": "InternalIP"
                    },
                    {
                        "address": "kind2-control-plane",
                        "type": "Hostname"
                    }
                ],
    ...
}

$ kubectl get nodes --output jsonpath='{.items[*].status.addresses}'
[map[address:172.17.0.3 type:InternalIP] map[address:kind2-control-plane type:Hostname]]
```

In the above examples, URL is http://127.17.0.3:30007.

Comment: The URL is wrong. It should be http://172.17.0.3:30007/

Comment: thanks, I put the nodePort in my config file that misses and then open with localhost:30007 it works, I use docker desktop with kubernetes enabled

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment file does not have any selector for Pods which would be used by service!

If you want specific port, update the port info in the service section itself. Otherwise k8s will assign some random ports which you get by running `kubectl get svc`

Try this file. Access the application at port 30080

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tomcat-app
  name: tomcat-app
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: tomcatapp:v1.0.0
        name: tomcat-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tomcat-app
  name: tomcat-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: tomcat-app
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: tried with your deployment file also but still the same result cant access the service on nodeport specified

Comment: @JayD, are you using minikube? if yes, it wont work on localhost. you need to find the minikube ip by running this `minikube ip` and use it to access it with the node port