# Cant access Kubernetes service with docker desktop on win10 machine

Tags: kubernetes, service, docker-desktop

this is my pod.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: voting-app
      image: kodekloud/examplevotingapp_vote:v1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and this is my service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels: 
    name: voting-service
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30004
  selector:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
```

after executing

```
kubectl get pods,svc
```

i get

```
NAME                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

pod/voting-app-pod   1/1     Running   0          37m

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE

service/kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        11d

service/voting-service   NodePort    10.107.145.225   <none>        80:30004/TCP   6m45s
```

I tried to a access  the service trough http://localhost:30004 and also i tried
http://127.0.0.1:30004
with no success

Comment: Check the similar issues it might be helpful :
[Stack Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171918/19230181),
[Stack Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50178697/19230181).

Let me know if this helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you able to access now and Is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have selector and template label declaration in deployment as below.  For more details on the attributes, refer [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-voting-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-voting-app
```

And in service as below

```
selector:
  app: demo-voting-app
```